# Web crawler returns zero pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, data-mining

I'm trying to create a spider from the results of this [page](https://www.in.gov.br/consulta/-/buscar/dou?q=*&s=do1&s=doe&exactDate=personalizado&sortType=0&delta=20&publishFrom=01%2F10%2F2021&publishTo=31%2F12%2F2021&orgPrin=Minist%C3%A9rio+da+Sa%C3%BAde)

When I call the `runspider` function on the scraped results I get zero crawled pages returned.

There are further errors that I do not understand. I'm a beginner and this project is new to me.

My code it is:

`

```
import scrapy

class SusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'susManagement'
    allowed_domains = ['in.gov.br/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.in.gov.br/consulta/-/buscar/dou?q=*&s=do1&s=doe&exactDate=personalizado&sortType=0&delta=20&publishFrom=01%2F10%2F2021&publishTo=31%2F12%2F2021&orgPrin=Minist%C3%A9rio+da+Sa%C3%BAde']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        gates = response.xpath("//div[@class='resultado']//h5[@class='title-marker']//a")
        for gate in gates:
            gate_number = gate.xpath(".//text()").get()
            link_gate = gate.xpath(".//@href").get()
            yield response.follow(url=link_gate, callback=self.parse_text,
                    meta={'gate_name': gate_number})
        next_page = response.xpath("//div//ul/li[@class='page-item active']/button")
        if next_page:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse_text(self, response):
        portaria = response.request.meta['gate_name']
        num_portaria = response.xpath("*//section//div//p[@class='identifica']/text()").re('.*')
        texto = response.xpath("//section//div//p[@class='texto-dou']/text()").re('.*')
        ementa = response.xpath("//article//div//p[@class='ementa']/text()").re('.*')
        rest_texto = texto - ementa - num_portaria
        
        yield {
            'port_name': portaria,
            'numero_port': num_portaria,
            'classified': ementa,
            'texto_integral': rest_texto
        }
```

`

I have tried to change the sequence of my `parse` functions.  By clicking on each file after its finished.

At the moment I want to create a `csv` file with the documents of the output and separate them by columns.

[image: Updated error]

Comment: I just change the page_number for pages, after reading the full shell errors.

Comment: How are you invoking the code?  The source you posted does not run as is.  That is a very important detail to have in order to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you completely. But I'm using " scrapy runspider projetosus.py -o datasusmanage.csv " this on a virtual enviroment that I've Install the python and scrapy before.

Comment: your parse method isn't doing anything you get a `page_number` variable and then you iterate a non-existing variable `pages`  where does `pages` come from?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that but I already fix it and the result is this other one.

Comment: @SureForU the problem is in the `parse` method. Your pagination is wrong.

Comment: @SureForU that was exactly what I was asking for, thank you.

Comment: That pagination was really wrong, I'm trying to think on how to put that and still get me inside of each link getting the information that I want to. As soon as I change the code I'll put here if theres any errors.

Comment: I put one pagination, I'm not really sure if it is allright. But the 0 crawled items still remain. I dont know exacly the reason.